# How to Add Menu Item to Parent Using Civix

Tags: extension, menu, civix

I'm trying to add a menu item for my extension to the existing "Memberships" menu. The documentation suggests the following:

> Use the Civix implementation
>
> Civix comes with helper functions
>   _EXTENSION_NAME_civix_insert_navigation_menu and _EXTENSION_NAME_civix_navigation_menu that simplify the process of inserting menu items. Consider using these functions rather than using
>   the examples below or writing your own implementation of this hook.

What it doesn't do is give you any clue how to do this. I found an example here: https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md.

Regardless, there is no info on how to actually add a menu item to an existing menu using this method.

**Could someone please enlighten me on how to use the civix method to add a menu item as a child to an existing menu?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_navigationMenu().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/
 */
function dmfactuurlink_civicrm_navigationMenu(&$menu) {

  _dmfactuurlink_civix_insert_navigation_menu($menu, 'Administer', array(
    'label' => E::ts('Domus Medica Factuur Link Instellingen'),
    'name' => 'dmafctuurlink_setting',
    'url' => 'civicrm/dmfactuurlink/form/setting',
    'permission' => 'administer CiviCRM',
    'attributes' => [],
    'operator' => 'OR',
    'separator' => 0,
  ));
  _dmfactuurlink_civix_navigationMenu($menu);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific part of this that lets me change the position (weight) of the link within the menu hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. The following line:

```
_serving_civix_insert_navigation_menu($menu, NULL, array(
```

should have the name of the parent menu passed as:

```
_serving_civix_insert_navigation_menu($menu, 'Memberships', array(
```

That will place the menu item within the existing "Memberships" menu.

Anyone know how to change the position of the menu item?